# DSL modem in bridge mode but router not accessible from the internet

Tags: networking, firewall, router, bridge, adsl

I have a DLink ADSL modem which I have put into bridge mode and connected to a Fortigate 200A firewall. The Fortigate is able to connect through PPPoE and receives the static public IP. I can browse the internet through the Fortigate with this configuration.

However, the public IP on the Fortigate is not accessible from outside. I cannot ping it and I cannot connect to the Fortigate's admin UI using the ADSL public IP (I have enabled ping and admin access on this wan interface). Any virtual server policies I implement also don't work.

Any ideas on what I'm missing? If you need any additional info please just let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to access the public IP from behind the router? If so, that would require that the router support hairpin NAT, which it may or may not do.

Comment: Nope, trying from my home connection (router/modem are the office)